# Calendar month view error

Tags: solspace, plugin-solspacecalendar, calendar, plugin-calendar

I recently installed Calendar (latest 1.9.3) on my Craft install (latest 2.6.2997)

Within the demo templates provided by Calendar (/calendar_demo/), the month view, I am getting the following error:

`Fatal error: Call to a member function getTimestamp() on boolean in ../craft/app/helpers/DbHelper.php on line 597`

I have seem to narrow it down to the targetDate variable being set to "today"

`{% set targetDate = "today" %}`

However, if i go to the following url: `/calendar_demo/month/2017/11` the month view works but the test event I have doesn't show.

What am I missing here?

I am on a Pro license and only plugins I have installed are:

- Contact Form (P&T)
- Focus Point
- Instagram Feed (currently disabled)
- Minimee
- Polls (currently disabled)
- Relabel

Again now sure what I am missing here any point in the right direction is welcomed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATED RESPONSE...**

We were finally able to get to the bottom of this and traced the issue down to your site likely having a **DateTime** field with the handle `date`, and this was apparently something Craft was choking on.

The next version of Calendar will fix this, but you can resolve this by renaming that **DateTime** field or patch this by looking for this code in *calendar/services/Calendar_EventsService.php* around *line 100*:

```
public function getEventList($criteria = null)
{
    if (!isset($criteria['allowedCalendarsOnly'])) {
        $criteria['allowedCalendarsOnly'] = false;
    }
```

And right after that, add this:

```
    if (isset($criteria['date'])) {
        unset($criteria['date']);
    }
```

Let me know if this resolves the issue for you. :)

Comment: This shows the calendar, but any events added do not show at all

Comment: We're having a very difficult time trying to reproduce this issue. Are you at all able to create a support ticket and provide us with a CP login on your site for us to test this out? :)

Comment: I can. I'll get that submitted

Comment: Updated our answer here to display confirmed solution :)

Comment: Field has been changed. Appreciate the help!